# Writing serializable subclass

Tags: java, serialization

I'm reading J. Bloch's effective Java and now I'm at the section about serialization. He said that

> If a class that is designed for inheritance is not serializable, it
>   may be impossible to write a serializable subclass. Specifically, **it**
>   **will be impossible if the superclass does not provide an accessible**
>   **parameterless constructor**.

I don't understand that restriction. I tried this on the following classes:

```
private static class Base {

    private int i;
    private Object o;

    public Base(int i, Object o){
        if(i == 0 || o == null)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("The arguments are not accepted by this constructor");
        this.i = i;
        this.o = o;
    }

    private void readObjectNoData() throws InvalidObjectException{
        throw new InvalidObjectException("Stream data required");
    }
}

private static class Derived extends Base implements Serializable{

    public Derived(int i, Object o) {
        super(i, o);
    }

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
}
```

and actually, I can serialize an instance of `Derived`,  but when I try to desirealize it, I got the exception:

```
java.io.InvalidClassException: com.pack.age.SerializableTest$Derived; no valid constructor
```

Couldn't you explain the point of such things? I don't understand why they require paramtereless constructor in that case.

Comment: Because the code is try to reconstruct in-memory a class and part of the requirements is that it has a parameter-less public constructor

Answer (score 4, accepted):

When Java creates a `Derived` object (by any means), it has to be able to correctly initialize the state of the `Base` class. When you use `new Derived(0, null)`, the constructor for `Derived` knows which constructor of `Base` to call to make sure that `Base` is set up properly.

When deserializing an object, Java doesn't use the constructor; it uses a separate backdoor mechanism to set the state of a `Serializable` object. In this case, though, the JVM doesn't know how to call a superclass constructor; the only thing it can do is call a no-arg constructor (so that the class can initialize its own private fields appropriately).

Perhaps `Base` has some sort of internal state (kept in private fields) that `Derived` can't see. This state isn't serialized (because `Base` doesn't implement `Serializable`), and without a constructor to set it up, the `Base` part of the object could be in an inconsistent state.

Answer (score 2):

It is also required by api: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/io/Serializable.html

> To allow subtypes of non-serializable classes to be serialized, the
>   subtype may assume responsibility for saving and restoring the state
>   of the supertype's public, protected, and (if accessible) package
>   fields. The subtype may assume this responsibility only if the class
>   it extends has an accessible no-arg constructor to initialize the
>   class's state. It is an error to declare a class Serializable if this
>   is not the case. The error will be detected at runtime.
>
> During deserialization, the fields of non-serializable classes will be
>   initialized using the public or protected no-arg constructor of the
>   class. A no-arg constructor must be accessible to the subclass that is
>   serializable. The fields of serializable subclasses will be restored
>   from the stream.

When you deserialise the object from the file, you need to be able to instantiate the object. If you have multi parameter `constructor`, you wouldn't know how to instantiate it (what to pass to it).

Answer (score 1):

You need a parameterless constructor which can be called if you want to deserialize the object.

So additionally to your

```
public Base(int i, Object o)
```

add a parameterless constructor like

```
public Base()
```